# Treeview checkbox checked file and folder load in listview in C#

Tags: c#, treeview

I want to make an audit tool that aims to copy files and folders.

I use treeview to load files and folders using recursion method, but when treeview checked files and folders load in listview that requires huge times (21 minutes for 2GB). That is a problem.

How to load files and folders from treeview to listview within shortest time for faster calculation ?

Here's my code:

```
private void btnAddToListViewCheckedItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TreeNode tn in tvLoadTreeviewFromListView.Nodes)
    {

        AddToListView(tn);
    }
}

private void AddToListView(TreeNode tn)
{

    {

        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(tn.Text);

        string[] suffix = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            int s = 0;
            long size = file.Length;
            while (size >= 1024)
            {
                NO_OF_FILES += 1;
                s++;
                size /= 1024;
            }



            String countFileSize = string.Format("{0}{1}", size, suffix[s]);


            ListViewItem item = lvLoadSelectedFileAndFolder.Items.Add(file.Name);

            item.ImageIndex= sysIcons.GetIconIndex(tn.Text);
            item.SubItems.Add(tn.Text);
            item.SubItems.Add(countFileSize);

        }

        foreach (TreeNode tnx in tn.Nodes)
        {


            for (int i = 0; i < lvLoadSelectedFileAndFolder.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                int ii = 1;
                if (tnx.Text == lvLoadSelectedFileAndFolder.Items[i].SubItems[ii].Text)
                {
                    return;

                }
            }


            if (tnx.Checked)
            {

                AddToListView(tnx);
            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ){}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `suffix` array is basically a constant but will be reallocated on the heap every time `AddToListView` processes a filename that exists. Also, suspend UI updates while loading the listview. Try this ...

```
const string[] suffix = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB" };

private void btnAddToListViewCheckedItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        lvLoadSelectedFileAndFolder.BeginUpdate();
        foreach (TreeNode tn in tvLoadTreeviewFromListView.Nodes)
        {
            AddToListView(tn);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        lvLoadSelectedFileAndFolder.EndUpdate();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks.. But i can not access `lvLoadSelectedFileAndFolder.Items.BeginUpdate();` property.It is possible to access `lvLoadSelectedFileAndFolder.BeginUpdate();` Property.. Any method require to write?

Comment: Sorry, those methods are on the `ListView` not the `Items` property. I have corrected the code.